# MySQL Median in view

Tags: mysql, median

How would I calculate the median in a view?

My proplem isn't the median itself (still wondering why it's not implemented in MySQL), but calculation it in a view. Every solution so far requires a sub query, but these aren't allowed in a view, so I wonder if there is a workaround?

AVG badly isn't accurate enough in this scenario.